# How to do a efficiently check if a string partially exists in a much larger set?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, loops, set

Say I have a Set of Strings:

```
Set<String> things = new HashSet<String>();
things.add("coffee cup");
things.add("smartphone");
things.add("inkjet printer");
//   :
// list could be quite large (100K or so, perhaps loaded from a database)
//   :
```

Now I want to check if another string completely contains any of the Strings in the above set.  So:

```
"a coffee cup" - matches
"android smartphone" - matches
"inkjet printer for sale" - matches
"laser printer" - does not match
"printer" - does not match
```

The only way I can think of is iterating through the set (and break-ing if found).  Is there a more efficient and elegant way to do this?

Comment: In short: no. Probably you should use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) instead of a `Set<String>`

Comment: You could use a hash table to improve time, do you want me to elaborate in an answer, or must you use this format?

Comment: @Lugubrious a `Set` normally use a `Map` behind the scenes. Note that Java helps you create a `Set` from a `Map<Whatever, Boolean>` since Java 6 using [`Collections#newSetFromMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap%28java.util.Map%29)

Comment: It could be possible to use a trie or radix tree to store all "sane" substrings (full words), and use that for lookup. That comes with the cost of space though, and would not find "offee cup".

Comment: @Lugubrious I'm not sure how/why a hashtable would be faster.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: I thought I knew but Luiggi seems to think I'm incorrect. :/ My idea was that the hash would make it so you would only have to compare strings with the same hash values.

Comment: Luiggi and Kiheru - trying to wrap my head around using a trie.  I'm thinking it could work but am wondering what real-world performance increase I would get.  I think I'll give it a try/test.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need Aho-Corasick algorithm.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm

https://github.com/raymanrt/aho-corasick

Time complexity is O(m) for preprocessing (where m is total length of strings in the set) and O(n) for matching (where n is length of matched string). So it's asymptotically optimal.

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over all substrings of the candidate, and check whether the set contains them?

```
boolean containsSubstring(Set<String> set, String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length; j++) {
            if (set.contains(str.substring(i,j))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Yes, a string of length k has k^2 substrings, but that may still be far less than the number of strings in the set ...

Comment: I like this...very clever!

Comment: Dear downvoter: while I am sure there are more efficient algorithms to solve this problem, they are more complex to implement and understand - and the simple algorithm I presented may already be fast enough. Also, if we are at liberty to tokenize by word boundaries, this simple algorithm may even be faster than the standard data structure for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I built off of @meriton's suggestion.  Instead of every possible substring combination, I'm going to do every possible word combination.

```
Set<String> permutations = new HashSet<String>();

String [] arr = token.split(" ");  
int size = arr.length;

for (int i = size ; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < i; j++) {

        StringBuilder permutation = new StringBuilder();
        permutation.append(arr[j]);
        for (int k = j+1  ; k < i; k++) {
            permutation.append(" ");
            permutation.append(arr[k]);
        }
        permutations.add(permutation.toString());

    }
}
```

If I run "inkjet printer for sale" through the code snippet above, I get:

- inkjet printer for sale
- printer for sale
- for sale
- sale
- inkjet printer for
- printer for
- for
- inkjet printer
- printer
- inkjet

Then I can do a simple `contains()` on the original set of words.