# Optimal approach to find occurrences of each phrase from a list in a string in Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm, performance, arraylist

I searched quite a bit on this and most posts are talking either about finding common strings between 2 arraylists which can be done with Collections.retainAll or an ArrayList containing individual words compared against text.

I have text which may look something like this in Java.

```
String text = "Get a placement right today by applying to our interviews and don't forget to email us your resume. This is a top job opportunity to get yourself acquainted with real world programming and skill building. Hurry! apply for placement now here";
```

I have an ArrayList that has lets say 2 strings, "placement" and "job opportunity"

I would like the results as placement(2) and job opportunity(1)
There are several approaches I have in mind currently but I would like to know the optimal way for achieving this.

**Approach 1**
Maintain a counter for each word in the ArrayList. For each word in the ArrayList, execute a text.contains(word) and if its true, increment the corresponding counter, What happens if there are more words in the text than the ArrayList or more words in the ArrayList than the text here? Is there any optimal or shorter way to achieve the same? I may have words or phrases in my ArrayList. Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645261/how-to-do-a-efficiently-check-if-a-string-partially-exists-in-a-much-larger-set) previous SO question might be of help.

Comment: Check out the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm).

Comment: Do you need an "optimal" algorithm (optimal with respect to what, by the way), or do you need a sufficient algorithm (i.e. one that is good enough)?

Comment: @AndyTurner Turner , i am doing a check for spam words or phrases inside a paragraph, there are 25 paragraphs that i need to process at max on each run and the number of phrases or words in my set can go anywhere from 1 - 10000, the paragraphs will mostly have between 0-1000 words and not more than that, this will be running on a background thread on mobile device so resource usage would be the constraint, I am going through the Aho Corasick algorithm currently but what would be a sufficient algorithm for this? thanks in advance

Comment: @npinti thanks for the suggestion, going through it now

Comment: A sufficient algorithm is one which meets your requirements, e.g. input size, running time, memory usage, ease of implementation, which you haven't stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly this problem is an instance of pattern matching problem.
[This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) lists the optimal string searching algorithms along with their average and worst case complexities.
If I remember correctly Design and analysis of algorithms by Alfred V. Aho, Jerffery Ullman and John E. Hopcroft has a analysis of the [Finite-state automaton based search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) in the pattern matching chapter.

Following two seem to be most efficient.

1. [KMP matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)
2. [Boyer Moore string search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)

I found the implementation of both of the algorithms on http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu
I'll copy the files here too in case links go down.
Implementations:

1. [KMP implementation](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/KMP.java.html) (Time Complexity Θ(m) + Θ(n))
2. [Boyer Moore implementation](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/BoyerMoore.java.html) (Time Complexity Θ(m + k) + O(n))

***StdOut*** is simply **System.out**

**Backup KMP:**

```
/******************************************************************************
 *  Compilation:  javac KMP.java
 *  Execution:    java KMP pattern text
 *  Dependencies: StdOut.java
 *
 *  Reads in two strings, the pattern and the input text, and
 *  searches for the pattern in the input text using the
 *  KMP algorithm.
 *
 *  % java KMP abracadabra abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad
 *  text:    abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad 
 *  pattern:               abracadabra          
 *
 *  % java KMP rab abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad
 *  text:    abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad 
 *  pattern:         rab
 *
 *  % java KMP bcara abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad
 *  text:    abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad 
 *  pattern:                                   bcara
 *
 *  % java KMP rabrabracad abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad 
 *  text:    abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad
 *  pattern:                        rabrabracad
 *
 *  % java KMP abacad abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad
 *  text:    abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad
 *  pattern: abacad
 *
 ******************************************************************************/

/**
 *  The <tt>KMP</tt> class finds the first occurrence of a pattern string
 *  in a text string.
 *  <p>
 *  This implementation uses a version of the Knuth-Morris-Pratt substring search
 *  algorithm. The version takes time as space proportional to
 *  <em>N</em> + <em>M R</em> in the worst case, where <em>N</em> is the length
 *  of the text string, <em>M</em> is the length of the pattern, and <em>R</em>
 *  is the alphabet size.
 *  <p>
 *  For additional documentation,
 *  see <a href="http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring">Section 5.3</a> of
 *  <i>Algorithms, 4th Edition</i> by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.
 */
public class KMP {
    private final int R;       // the radix
    private int[][] dfa;       // the KMP automoton

    private char[] pattern;    // either the character array for the pattern
    private String pat;        // or the pattern string

    /**
     * Preprocesses the pattern string.
     *
     * @param pat the pattern string
     */
    public KMP(String pat) {
        this.R = 256;
        this.pat = pat;

        // build DFA from pattern
        int M = pat.length();
        dfa = new int[R][M]; 
        dfa[pat.charAt(0)][0] = 1; 
        for (int X = 0, j = 1; j < M; j++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < R; c++) 
                dfa[c][j] = dfa[c][X];     // Copy mismatch cases. 
            dfa[pat.charAt(j)][j] = j+1;   // Set match case. 
            X = dfa[pat.charAt(j)][X];     // Update restart state. 
        } 
    } 

    /**
     * Preprocesses the pattern string.
     *
     * @param pattern the pattern string
     * @param R the alphabet size
     */
    public KMP(char[] pattern, int R) {
        this.R = R;
        this.pattern = new char[pattern.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < pattern.length; j++)
            this.pattern[j] = pattern[j];

        // build DFA from pattern
        int M = pattern.length;
        dfa = new int[R][M]; 
        dfa[pattern[0]][0] = 1; 
        for (int X = 0, j = 1; j < M; j++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < R; c++) 
                dfa[c][j] = dfa[c][X];     // Copy mismatch cases. 
            dfa[pattern[j]][j] = j+1;      // Set match case. 
            X = dfa[pattern[j]][X];        // Update restart state. 
        } 
    } 

    /**
     * Returns the index of the first occurrrence of the pattern string
     * in the text string.
     *
     * @param  txt the text string
     * @return the index of the first occurrence of the pattern string
     *         in the text string; N if no such match
     */
    public int search(String txt) {

        // simulate operation of DFA on text
        int M = pat.length();
        int N = txt.length();
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < N && j < M; i++) {
            j = dfa[txt.charAt(i)][j];
        }
        if (j == M) return i - M;    // found
        return N;                    // not found
    }

    /**
     * Returns the index of the first occurrrence of the pattern string
     * in the text string.
     *
     * @param  text the text string
     * @return the index of the first occurrence of the pattern string
     *         in the text string; N if no such match
     */
    public int search(char[] text) {

        // simulate operation of DFA on text
        int M = pattern.length;
        int N = text.length;
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < N && j < M; i++) {
            j = dfa[text[i]][j];
        }
        if (j == M) return i - M;    // found
        return N;                    // not found
    }


    /** 
     * Takes a pattern string and an input string as command-line arguments;
     * searches for the pattern string in the text string; and prints
     * the first occurrence of the pattern string in the text string.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pat = args[0];
        String txt = args[1];
        char[] pattern = pat.toCharArray();
        char[] text    = txt.toCharArray();

        KMP kmp1 = new KMP(pat);
        int offset1 = kmp1.search(txt);

        KMP kmp2 = new KMP(pattern, 256);
        int offset2 = kmp2.search(text);

        // print results
        StdOut.println("text:    " + txt);

        StdOut.print("pattern: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < offset1; i++)
            StdOut.print(" ");
        StdOut.println(pat);

        StdOut.print("pattern: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < offset2; i++)
            StdOut.print(" ");
        StdOut.println(pat);
    }
}
```

**Backup Boyer Moore:**

```
BoyerMoore.java


Below is the syntax highlighted version of BoyerMoore.java from §5.3 Substring Search.


/******************************************************************************
 *  Compilation:  javac BoyerMoore.java
 *  Execution:    java BoyerMoore pattern text
 *  Dependencies: StdOut.java
 *
 *  Reads in two strings, the pattern and the input text, and
 *  searches for the pattern in the input text using the
 *  bad-character rule part of the Boyer-Moore algorithm.
 *  (does not implement the strong good suffix rule)
 *
 *  % java BoyerMoore abracadabra abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad
 *  text:    abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad 
 *  pattern:               abracadabra
 *
 *  % java BoyerMoore rab abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad
 *  text:    abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad 
 *  pattern:         rab
 *
 *  % java BoyerMoore bcara abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad
 *  text:    abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad 
 *  pattern:                                   bcara
 *
 *  % java BoyerMoore rabrabracad abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad
 *  text:    abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad
 *  pattern:                        rabrabracad
 *
 *  % java BoyerMoore abacad abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad
 *  text:    abacadabrabracabracadabrabrabracad
 *  pattern: abacad
 *
 ******************************************************************************/

/**
 *  The <tt>BoyerMoore</tt> class finds the first occurrence of a pattern string
 *  in a text string.
 *  <p>
 *  This implementation uses the Boyer-Moore algorithm (with the bad-character
 *  rule, but not the strong good suffix rule).
 *  <p>
 *  For additional documentation,
 *  see <a href="http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring">Section 5.3</a> of
 *  <i>Algorithms, 4th Edition</i> by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.
 */
public class BoyerMoore {
    private final int R;     // the radix
    private int[] right;     // the bad-character skip array

    private char[] pattern;  // store the pattern as a character array
    private String pat;      // or as a string

    /**
     * Preprocesses the pattern string.
     *
     * @param pat the pattern string
     */
    public BoyerMoore(String pat) {
        this.R = 256;
        this.pat = pat;

        // position of rightmost occurrence of c in the pattern
        right = new int[R];
        for (int c = 0; c < R; c++)
            right[c] = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < pat.length(); j++)
            right[pat.charAt(j)] = j;
    }

    /**
     * Preprocesses the pattern string.
     *
     * @param pattern the pattern string
     * @param R the alphabet size
     */
    public BoyerMoore(char[] pattern, int R) {
        this.R = R;
        this.pattern = new char[pattern.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < pattern.length; j++)
            this.pattern[j] = pattern[j];

        // position of rightmost occurrence of c in the pattern
        right = new int[R];
        for (int c = 0; c < R; c++)
            right[c] = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < pattern.length; j++)
            right[pattern[j]] = j;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the index of the first occurrrence of the pattern string
     * in the text string.
     *
     * @param  txt the text string
     * @return the index of the first occurrence of the pattern string
     *         in the text string; N if no such match
     */
    public int search(String txt) {
        int M = pat.length();
        int N = txt.length();
        int skip;
        for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i += skip) {
            skip = 0;
            for (int j = M-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (pat.charAt(j) != txt.charAt(i+j)) {
                    skip = Math.max(1, j - right[txt.charAt(i+j)]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (skip == 0) return i;    // found
        }
        return N;                       // not found
    }


    /**
     * Returns the index of the first occurrrence of the pattern string
     * in the text string.
     *
     * @param  text the text string
     * @return the index of the first occurrence of the pattern string
     *         in the text string; N if no such match
     */
    public int search(char[] text) {
        int M = pattern.length;
        int N = text.length;
        int skip;
        for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i += skip) {
            skip = 0;
            for (int j = M-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (pattern[j] != text[i+j]) {
                    skip = Math.max(1, j - right[text[i+j]]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (skip == 0) return i;    // found
        }
        return N;                       // not found
    }


    /**
     * Takes a pattern string and an input string as command-line arguments;
     * searches for the pattern string in the text string; and prints
     * the first occurrence of the pattern string in the text string.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pat = args[0];
        String txt = args[1];
        char[] pattern = pat.toCharArray();
        char[] text    = txt.toCharArray();

        BoyerMoore boyermoore1 = new BoyerMoore(pat);
        BoyerMoore boyermoore2 = new BoyerMoore(pattern, 256);
        int offset1 = boyermoore1.search(txt);
        int offset2 = boyermoore2.search(text);

        // print results
        StdOut.println("text:    " + txt);

        StdOut.print("pattern: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < offset1; i++)
            StdOut.print(" ");
        StdOut.println(pat);

        StdOut.print("pattern: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < offset2; i++)
            StdOut.print(" ");
        StdOut.println(pat);
    }
}


Copyright © 2002–2015, Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.
Last updated: Sat Aug 29 11:16:30 EDT 2015.
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach would be to search for each of the words in the list using `String.indexOf`:

```
for (String word : list) {
  int prev = -1;
  int count = 0;
  do {
    prev = s.indexOf(word, prev + 1);
    if (prev != -1 /* && check for word breaks */) {
      count++
    }
  } while (prev != -1);
  System.out.println(word + " " + count);
}
```

However, this is not designed to be optimal with respect to any particular criterion, other than simplicity.

Note that this does not check for word breaks, so it would find `"foo"` in `"xfoox"`; it would be possible to change the condition where I have indicated to look for these.

If you need to process a very large list of words, an algorithm like [Aho-Corasick](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) would be more efficient, since this would avoid the need to check all strings in the list. However, it requires some preprocessing of the list of words, although that can be implemented reasonably efficiently, and can be done once offline for a given list of words.