# apply extraction information with java

Tags: java

i trying to apply  a dictionary (File of Words) on text(File of text):

we test if the word exists in a line of the text, if yes we will print it (the line). we test all word of dictionary for every line of text.

i used EXPREG pattern+matcher but the problem is the time. the operation take 5H.

The 2 File have 3330ko and 55ko 
.
my question is is there another method to do this like UNITEX but in java

```
public class Tratemant_Dic extends Thread {

    Tratemant_Dic() {

    }

    public void run() {
        try {

            BufferedReader file_corpus = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                            "corpus-medical.TXT"), "UTF-16LE"));

            PrintWriter ecrire = new PrintWriter("sort.html");
            String line;
            String nom = null;

            ecrire.write("<mot><span style=\"color:red\">startsss</span></mot></br><ligne>start\n");
            while ((line = file_corpus.readLine()) != null) {

                BufferedReader file_nom = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                                "Fichie_sorte.DIC"), "UTF-16LE"));
                while ((nom = file_nom.readLine()) != null) {
                    nom = nom.substring(0, nom.length() - 3);
                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\W+" + nom + "\\b.*",
                            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

                    if (m.find()) {

                        System.out.println(nom + "==>" + line);
                        ecrire.write("<mot><span style=\"color:red\">" + nom
                                + "</span></mot></br><ligne>" + line + "\n");

                    }

                }

                file_nom.close();

            }
            ecrire.close();
            System.out.println("FIN");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the size of the input and dictionary ?

Comment: Just looking at the code, for each line you read from  `corpus-medical.TXT`
1. why you are reading `Fichie_sorte.DIC` for each line? Just read it only once, that should already save your time. 
2. Since your `Fichie_sorte.DIC` doesnt change, that means all the regex you are compiling doesnt need to be compiled for each line of `corpus-medical.TXT`. This should also reduce time and also memory.

Comment: Check apache commons IO http://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file and after optimize your regex strategy

Comment: Check this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645806/optimal-approach-to-find-occurrences-of-each-phrase-from-a-list-in-a-string-in-j/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, I would not use regular expressions to do it.  They're slow and you do not need them.

This is really a string matching problem.  Your dictionary should probably be stored in a hash table, using the hashCode() method to get a key for the string.  You then search in your dictionary for each word as you read it ( calculating the appropriate hash code as you read it ) from the text.  Properly done that should be as fast as it gets.

Remember that hash codes are *not* guaranteed to be unique, so always make sure the actual strings match even if the hash code is found in the table.

Comment: Good am ok with that . my probleme is how test if a word exite in line String or no with out String.indexof or string.equal  . i want use Unitex methde or MITIE  https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE

Comment: i want use  tools for information extraction in my application

Comment: What you described in was word searching, but what you are asking for now involves grammar matching as well, if I understand you.  That is a very much more complex task.  Have I misunderstood you ?

Comment: Non .i trying to extract information if the word of my dictionary exist in the line of the text

Comment: I think the problem you are trying to explain is that you think you need to compare a substring in the input to the dictionary strings.  You should really be scanning the text in a way that detects the start and end of words and then each time you heave read in a complete word you should have just that word in a string to lookup in the table.

Comment: Non .
just i want to have save the line that one word of Dictionary existe in .

Answer (score 0):

Why you not use instead of

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\W+" + nom + "\\b.*",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

        if (m.find()) {
         ...
```

just

```
if(line.indexOf(nom) > -1) {
     ...
```

?

**Update:** if you need word boundary stuff use something:

```
String lineToLowerCase = line.toLowerCase();  // before second while
...
    int index = lineToLowerCase.indexOf(nom.toLowerCase());
    if(index > -1) {
        if(index ==0 || Character.isWhitespace(lineToLowerCase.charAt(index-1))) {
            int indexEnd = index + nom.length();
            if (indexEnd >= lineToLowerCase.length() || !Character.isAlphabetic(lineToLowerCase.charAt(indexEnd))) {
       ...
```

for testing

```
public static void main(String[] s) {
    check("skdc s dcd dsf", "dcd"); // print true
    check("skdc sdcd dsf", "dcd"); // print false
    check("dcd dsf", "dcd"); // print true
    check("afasa dcd", "dcd"); // print true
    check("afasa dCD11", "dcD"); // print true
    check("skdc s dcda dsf", "dcd"); // print false
}

public static void check(String line, String nom) {
    String lineToLowerCase = line.toLowerCase();
    int index = lineToLowerCase.indexOf(nom.toLowerCase());
    if(index > -1) {
        if(index ==0 || Character.isWhitespace(lineToLowerCase.charAt(index-1))) {
            int indexEnd = index + nom.length();
            if (indexEnd >= lineToLowerCase.length() || !Character.isAlphabetic(lineToLowerCase.charAt(indexEnd))) {
                System.out.println("true");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("false");
}
```

Comment: The regex does word boundary stuff where as yours does now.

Comment: What is word boundary stuff in your task?

Comment: \W+ is one more more [none word char](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html) and the \b is [word boundary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html).

Comment: I'm not sure that works in quite the same was as the regex, but I'd have to do some checks to be sure. But it is likely good enough.

Comment: i didn't use Indexof() pecause it returne the index of sub word

Comment: for exemple String s="skdc sdcd dsf " and am searching the string "dcd" it return true but i won't this . i want return ture if i find "skdc s dcd dsf"

Comment: yes, but code after update it's the quite same as  EXPREG pattern+matcher, nowever working much faster

Comment: use code after update, that returns true only if "skdc s dcd dsf", not in case of "skdc sdcd dsf "

Comment: I add testing example with  "skdc s dcd dsf" and "skdc sdcd dsf "

Comment: I didn't understand you

Comment: if we have  "skdc s dcd dsf" and "skdc sdcd dsf " it well printf false

Comment: Do you use my example in the end of post?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by attempting to time each of the "things" your application does than then target the slowest item (as mentioned in a comment by [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471467/jay), one issue in your case is the fact you are loading the dictionary every time) rather than base the improvements on a guess of what is wrong (the regex being slow).

You can use [`System.nanoTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) or one of the many stopwatches to do this. I normally use [guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html).

Comment: the File of word Dictionary have 1632 line i can't saved it memore

Comment: Each line a word? That is not much at all.

Comment: Reading other comments it sounds like you want NLP. Maybe it is worth indexing everything into something like Lucene and using that?

Comment: Why can't you store the dictionary? At say 10 chars per word I make that less than a meg of storage.

Comment: the file of dictionary have 55ko

Comment: alemtuzumab,.N
alfacalcidol,.N
alfentanil,.N
alfuzosine,.N
alglucosidase alfa,.N
alimémazine,.N
aliskirène,.N
alitrétinoïne,.N
alizapride,.N
allopurinol,.N
alminoprofène,.N
almitrine,.N
almotriptan,.N
alpha-1-antitrypsine,.N
alpha-tocophérol,.N
alprazolam,.N

and

Comment: and corpus file is like thisd :
Hospitalisation : 03 22 66 82 39
Consultation : 03 22 66 82 35 – Télécopie : 03 22 66 88 47
Hôpital de Jour : 03 22 66 82 38 – Télécopie : 03 22 66 88 14
MasculinMonsieur XXX XXX (XXX/XXX/XXX)
Visite du 25/08/2009
Etabli par : Docteur G. DAMAJ 
Destinataires : Dr MUTTI 
GD/CD – 09/620
Sur le plan hématologique nous sommes à J13 de l’induction. Il est en aplasie. Les besoins transfusionnels sont faibles.
Des hémocultures ont poussé (4 flacons) à staph coag - méti R. La VA
Apyrétique sous traitement par TAZOCILLINE-VANCOMYCINE et prévention par NOXAFIL.

Comment: and we well save the laste line
 Apyrétique sous traitement par TAZOCILLINE-VANCOMYCINE et prévention par NOXAFIL.

Comment: 55,000 objects? How big is each object. Have you tried loading them all?

Comment: I'm not questioning if you need it all, I'm asking if you really can not store it all in memory. Have you tried?